# Argument 1 passed to ::showAll() must be an instance of Collection, instance ofCollection given, called BuyerProductController.php on line 23

Tags: laravel

I don't understand this mistake, can someone help me?

I am taking a course on ApiRestfull and the code works for the teacher but I can't get it to work for me

I am using laravel 5.8*

The error he shows me is this: Error:

Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::showAll() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection, instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection given, called in C:\laragon\www\udemy-apirestfull\app\Http\Controllers\Buyer\BuyerProductController.php on line 23

BuyerProductController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Buyer;

use App\Buyer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\ApiController;

class BuyerProductController extends ApiController
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Buyer $buyer)
    {
         $products = $buyer->transactions()->with('product')
             ->get()
             ->pluck('product');


            return $this->showAll($products);
    }
}
```

ApiController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Traits\ApiResponser;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    use ApiResponser;
}
```

ApiResponser:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

trait ApiResponser
{
    private function successResponse($data, $code)
    {
        return response()->json($data, $code);
    }

    protected function errorResponse($message, $code)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => $message, 'code' => $code], $code);
    }

    protected function showAll(Collection $collection, $code = 200)
    {
        return $this->successResponse(['data' => $collection], $code);
    }

    protected function showOne(Model $instance, $code = 200)
    {
        return $this->successResponse(['data' => $instance], $code);
    }
}
```

Buyer model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Transaction;
use App\Scopes\BuyerScope;


    class Buyer extends User
    {
        protected static function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();
    
            static::addGlobalScope(new BuyerScope);
        }
    
        public function transactions()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
        }
    }
```

Product Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Seller;
use App\Category;
use App\Transaction;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    const PRODUCTO_DISPONIBLE = 'disponible';
    const PRODUCTO_NO_DISPONIBLE = 'no disponible';


    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'quantity',
        'status',
        'image',
        'seller_id',
    ];
    public function estaDisponible()
    {
        return $this->status == Product::PRODUCTO_DISPONIBLE;
    }

    public function seller()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Seller::class);
    }

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }


}
```

Transaction Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Buyer;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'quantity',
        'buyer_id',
        'product_id',
    ];
    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Buyer::class);
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls post the code for showAll method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection extends Illuminate\Support\Collection

So if not mandatory, you can change the signature of showAll method to accept Illuminate\Support\Collection as a parameter

There will be no error if the parameter supplied will be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;  //Changed here

trait ApiResponser
{
    private function successResponse($data, $code)
    {
        return response()->json($data, $code);
    }

    protected function errorResponse($message, $code)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => $message, 'code' => $code], $code);
    }

    protected function showAll(Collection $collection, $code = 200)
    {
        return $this->successResponse(['data' => $collection], $code);
    }

    protected function showOne(Model $instance, $code = 200)
    {
        return $this->successResponse(['data' => $instance], $code);
    }
}
```